# Is it possible to receive HID mouse input (i.e. the raw data, not a cursor on-screen) in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, hid, human-interface, hid-device

Trying to utilize a mouse for a novel input device in our specialized iPad app.  Since iOS has HID drivers and mice are HID devices, is it possible to programmatically receive mouse movement deltas in code?

To be clear, I am not asking about an on-screen mouse cursor for iOS.  I mean strictly in the sense of reading programmatic input in my own specific app.

I'm also not talking about MFI devices which require you to develop hardware, then submit to have that hardware certified by Apple.  I'm referring again to a standard mouse using standard HID drivers which I believe are already part of the system (it recognizes HID keyboards already.)

So is something like this possible?

Comment: iOS does not support the mouse HID profile, only keyboards, so I don’t believe you will be able to get the data you are after.

Comment: What about at a lower-level then?  Any way to get at the raw data?

Comment: I use SwiftPoint GT mouse. SwiftPoint provides the SDK. Once you integrate the SDK into your application, you can use their mouse in your app.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer, possibly with a simple example snippet?  That would be helpful to those reading here.